# Transfer clothes from one 3d character to another

Tags: cloth-simulation, unity, .fbx

[image][image] I bought two character models from the unity asset store and I would like to transfer the clothing from one character to another. I am a programmer making my first Indie game hence this is my first time using Blender. If anyone could point me to the right direction, that would be great.

Models are in fbx format.

Licence for both assets allow for modification and commercial use.

Thank you.

Comment: hello maybe show a picture of your characters?

Comment: Added images for both characters

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try with the *Sculpt* tools? You can mask the parts you want with the *Mask* brush, so that they are not affected. You can inflate (or deflate) the parts you want with the *Mesh Filter* brush in *Inflate* mode. You can bend the arms with the *Pose* brush:

[image]

*Pose* brush:

[image]

*Mesh Filter* brush:

[image]